# Wordpress multisite htaccess redirection to new domain

Tags: redirect, htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

All posts URLs are redirecting successfully. But
the problem is my old multisite `site_id` is different from the new multisite `site_id`.

So all `site.olddomain.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/..`
is redirecting to `site.newdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/7/..`.

But the `site_id` at the new domain is `2`, not `7`.

I tried this

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.olddomain.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 
 https://site.newdomain.com/wpcontent/uploads/sites/7/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.olddomain.com$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site.olddomain\.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But still it is redirecting wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.olddomain.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2$
> ```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains just the hostname (the value of the `Host` HTTP request header). It does not contain the URL-path, so the above *condition* is never going to match.

> But the site_id in new domain is 2.

But your directive appears to be trying to do the opposite... checking for `2` on the `site.olddomain.com` and redirecting to `7` on the new domain? (But what about your other sites?)

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.newdomain.com/wpcontent/uploads/sites/7/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

You also appear to have omitted the hyphen (`-`) in `wpcontent`?

You need to write this specific redirect something like the following intsead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/sites)/2/(.*) https://site.newdomain.com/$1/7/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Some notes:

- Don't forget to escape the dots in the *pattern* to match literal dots (you've escaped some and not others).
- I've omitted the trailing `$` on the *CondPattern* that checks against HTTP_HOST in order to catch FQDN (that end in a dot).
- I've added the `NC` flag to the `RewriteCond` directive to make the check case-insensitive. This is really just to catch malformed requests (all *browsers* will lowercase the *hostname* in the request).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.olddomain.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site.olddomain\.com$
> ```

These two `RewriteCond` directives can be combined into one, by simply making the `www.` part *optional*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.olddomain\.com
```